# Plotting several implicit functions with legends

Tags: plotting

Here is how I am plotting the three implicit functions:

```
  Show [ ContourPlot[f[h, a] == 0, {a, 0, 0.6}, {h, 0, 1}, 
         ContourStyle -> Black], 
         ContourPlot[f2[h, a] == 0, {a, 0, 0.6}, {h, 0, 1}, 
         ContourStyle -> Red], 
         ContourPlot[f3[h, a] == 0, {a, 0, 0.6}, {h, 0, 1}, 
         ContourStyle -> Blue] ]
```

This works fine but I would like to add a legend, axis labels, larger fonts for the axes etc. I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: To come up with an answer, most of us would want to run tests with your code. But you give us code with undefined symbols that won't evaluate. I think you  are likely to get an answer if you would edit your question to include ***all** the code needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary functions:

```
f[h_, a_] := h^2 - a^2

f2[h_, a_] := 2 h^2 - a^3

f3[h_, a_] := h^2 - 2 a^2
```

A single [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) can handle multiple functions. This makes adding [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) and other shared options quite easy.

```
ContourPlot[
 {f[h, a] == 0, f2[h, a] == 0, f3[h, a] == 0},
 {a, 0, 0.6}, {h, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.25, 0.7}],
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image]